# Why does Mathematica recognize the conditional convergence of some integrals but not others?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, conditional

Consider the following two polynomials:

```
f1[t_] := t^3 - 1
f2[t_] := t^3 + 3t - 1
```

Both of these polynomials have a single real root:  $f_1(t)$ at $t = 1$, and $f_2(t)$ at $t \approx 0.322$. Both also satisfy $f'(t) > 0$ at all points in the interval.  Let's now try to do the integrals
$$
I_1 = \int_0^x \frac{f_1'(t)}{f_1(t)^2} dt \qquad \text{and} \qquad I_2 = \int_0^x \frac{f_2'(t)}{f_2(t)^2} dt
$$
for each of these polynomials.  (The closed-form indefinite integrals exist in both cases and are $-1/f_1$ and $-1/f_2$ respectively.)  We obtain:

```
integral1 = Integrate[D[f1[t],t] / f1[t]^2, {t, 0, x}]

(* ConditionalExpression[3 (-(1/3) + 1/(3 - 3 x^3)), Re[x] <= 1 || x ∉ Reals] *)

integral2 = Integrate[D[f2[t], t] / f2[t]^2, {t, 0, x}]

(* -1 + 1/(1 - 3 x - x^3) *)
```

For the first integral, Mathematica correctly recognizes that the integral only converges if $x < 1$.  However, it does not seem to be able to recognize that  the second integral only converges if $x \lesssim 0.322$.

**Is this a bug?  Is there a way to tell Integrate to apply additional transformations that might lead it to recognize the conditional convergence of $I_2$ in the same way that it does for $I_1$?**

To show that this could lead to unexpected behavior, note that if we set `x -> 2` in the above integrals we get

```
integral1 /. x -> 2

(* Undefined *)  

integral2 /. x -> 2

(* -(14/13) *)
```

But the integrand of $I_2$ is manifestly positive, and it shouldn't be possible to integrate a positive function to get a negative number.  Obviously this is due to the extension of this integral past its domain of applicability;  it would be nice if we could somehow modify Mathematica's behavior to tell us that we've done so in both of these cases, not just the case of $I_1$.

I am running Mathematica 10.4.1 on Mac OS X.

Comment: This question was inspired by [this question over on Math StackExchange.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282167/differential-equation-one-question-two-methods-both-result-in-different-ans/2282172)

Comment: If you take a complex path around the singularity, it seems to work: `Block[{x = 2.}, {NIntegrate[D[f2[t], t]/f2[t]^2, {t, 0, I, x + I, x}], -1 + 1/(1 - x (3 + x^2))}]` --  Oddly, adding assumptions that `x` is real leads to the condition `x > 0`.

Comment: Presumably any polynomial which does not obviously factor will have that problem...